# I would like to replace my page.php?var=# with /page/#

Tags: php, url, ip-address

As the question explains, I've seen this done countless times and it's absolutely fantastic and very modern, but have no idea how to start, where to start, what it's called, etc.

I have a page we'll assume is called page.php and using PHP GET, we can pull in data for a variable by the URL `domain.com/page.php?var=#`

What I would like to do is change that address too `domain.com/page/#` for a number of reasons:

1. It looks awesome. Very clean, very modern.
2. It's shorter.
3. I'd prefer the search engines pull that type of address than the
   first.

Is this a difficult thing? Does it take 5 minutes and a simple tutorial found somewhere?
Is there a performance hit by doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Answer (score 1):

It's called [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). You can use it in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?var=$1
```

It has nothing to do with PHP, it does just modify requested URIs. The code above will change (rewrite) the URL to `/page.php?var=xy` if `/page/xy` is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Move this to serverfault and use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?var=$1
```